# Inserting data to database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the following code

```
$input = Input::all();
 return $input;
```

It returns all the data I entered in the form.
Since all the data is available, I tried to insert data into database as

`$this->agro->create($input);`

When I check the database,the empty string is inserted.
I am confused,why the data is not inserted when the $input is displaying the inserted data in the form.
Please HELP!!!

**EDIT**

This is User Model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['title','content','author'];

    protected $table = 'tbl_article';
}
```

And this is my form

```
 {{@Form::open(['route'=>'agrovet.store'])}}

 <div>
 {{ @Form::label('lbl_title','Title') }}
 {{ @Form::text('title') }}
 </div>

 <div>
 {{ @Form::label('lbl_content','Content') }}
 {{ @Form::text('content') }}
 </div>

 <div>
 {{ @Form::label('lbl_author','Author') }}
 {{ @Form::text('author') }}
 </div>

 <div>
 {{ @form::submit('submit')}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Is `$fillable` set correctly in your model? [Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: Yea it's `protected $fillable = ['title','content','author'];`

Comment: Hmm can you update your question with the model code and the dump of `$input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of your text inputs are wrong. You should use the same name as your model attributes (and labels)

```
{{ @Form::label('title','Title') }}
{{ @Form::text('title') }}
```

and the same for the others...

Comment: Thanks a lot..it had been killing me from quit sometime.Please can you tell me why is it So in laravel. I  mean, I've never had such experience of using the same name for label and text before?

Comment: You're welcome. Well that's just basic HTML actually. The name you assign to the label doesn't really matter for the input the server get's. It is only needed so the browser knows which label belongs to which input.